# How do I teleport the turtle in Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, turtle-graphics

I am making a game in Python 3.6.4.

When the player touches the red circle, the player should teleport back to the start.

**Question 1:** How do I move the turtle to the start if it hits the red circle?

**My code:**

```
import turtle

wn = turtle.Screen()
wn.bgcolor("black")

player = turtle.Turtle()
player.color("white")
player.speed(0)
player.penup()
player.setposition(100, -110)

enemy = turtle.Turtle()
enemy.color("red")
enemy.shape("circle")
enemy.penup()
enemy.setposition(100, -100)

if player.pos(100, -100):
    player.pos(100, -110)
```

**The error I get is:**

`Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "C:\Users\ruffi\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\behg.p",     line 18, in <module>
    if player.pos(100, -100):
TypeError: pos() takes 1 positional argument but 3 were given`

**Question 2:** How do I fix this error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The approach I would take to solve both issues is don't do the position comparisons yourself, use the `distance()` method that turtle provides:

```
if player.distance(enemy) < 10:  # if the centers are within 10 pixels
```

Here's a complete example that lets you click on the screen to move the player around but if the player gets too close to the heart of the enemy, it will teleport back to the start where you can once again move by clicking on the screen:

```
from turtle import Turtle, Screen

wn = Screen()
wn.setup(500, 500)
wn.bgcolor('black')

player = Turtle(visible=False)
player.speed('fastest')
player.shapesize(2)
player.color('white')
player.penup()
player.setposition(200, -200)
player.showturtle()

enemy = Turtle('circle', visible=False)
enemy.shapesize(2)
enemy.color('red')
enemy.penup()
enemy.setposition(-200, 200)
enemy.showturtle()

def click_handler(x, y):
    wn.onclick(None)  # disable handler while in handler
    player.setheading(player.towards(x, y))  # head towards new location
    player.setposition(x, y)

    if player.distance(enemy) < 10:
        player.hideturtle()  # teleport
        player.setposition(200, -200)
        player.showturtle()

    wn.onclick(click_handler)

wn.onclick(click_handler)

wn.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 2):

`Turtle.pos()` *returns* the turtle’s position; it doesn’t *test* being present at a given position (as attempted by your `if` line) or *set* it (as attempted by your last line).  The former job is performed by [`Vec2D`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/turtle.html#turtle.Vec2D) comparison, while the latter is `Turtle.goto()`.

Separately, your code contains no provision for user input, so there is no way to “react” to the player arriving anywhere; perhaps you already know that.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that you are not familiar with the founction pos().This kind of arguments are  not satisfied requirement.I suggest you read the helping document agau

Answer (score 1):

In your if statement, you wrote `player.pos(100, -100)`.  `Turtle.pos()`returns the Turtle's position. To check if this position is equal to (100, -100), simple do: `if player.pos()==(100,-100)`. To make change the player's position, use `Turtle.goto(x,y)`. The following code should be what you are trying to do:

```
if player.pos()==(100,-100):
    player.goto(100, -110)
```

Hope this helps!